# Date compare in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to compare two dates in XSLT (1.0). Here I have mentioned hard coded dates

```
<xsl:variable name="DATE1" select="ms:format-date(16-FEB-19, 'dd-MMM-yy')" />
<xsl:variable name="DATE2" select="ms:format-date(01-MAY-19, 'dd-MMM-yy')" />

<xsl:if test="$DATE1 $lt; $DATE2">

</xsl:if>
```

I tried above but not getting proper result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSL: How to compare two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355600/xsl-how-to-compare-two-dates)

Comment: Where are the actual (not hard-coded) dates coming from, and in what format?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using some kind of extension function ms:format-date to format the dates. If you can format them as pure numeric YYYYMMDD then you can compare them as numbers. XSLT 1.0 does not offer a "<" operator for strings, let alone for dates.

Do think about moving forward to a later XSLT version (available from third parties) rather than asking the StackOverflow community to help you use a 20-year old version of the language.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for help with XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Agreed, there's nothing wrong with asking for help with any technology, but there's also nothing wrong with advising people that other more modern technologies would make the user's life easier.