# I need to pick the greater date of 2 dates coming at the same node in XSLT 1.0: <Date>2021-09-13-07:00 2021-12-25-08:00</Date>

Tags: xslt

```xml
<Date>2021-09-13-07:00 2021-12-25-08:00</Date>
```

I am using XSLT 1.0
I need to be able to select the higher of the 2 dates and pass it for further processing. I tried 'Max' function, it did not work. I tried sort Descending and select position 1, it did not work.

Comment: convert the dates to number first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32355600/xsl-how-to-compare-two-dates

Answer (score 2):

The format of your input is most inconvenient. XML has a structure of elements  and attributes; there is no reason to cram two dates together in a single text node.

As a result of this, the code required here will be rather lengthy. Here is one option:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Date">
    <!-- separate dates -->
    <xsl:variable name="date1" select="substring-before(., ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="date2" select="substring-after(., ' ')" />
    <!-- extract date parts -->
    <xsl:variable name="d1" select="translate(substring($date1, 1, 10), '-', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="d2" select="translate(substring($date2, 1, 10), '-', '')" />
    <!-- output -->
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- compare date parts -->
            <xsl:when test="$d1 > $d2">
                <xsl:value-of select="$date1" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$d2 > $d1">
                <xsl:value-of select="$date2" />
            </xsl:when>
            <!-- if dates are equal, compare offsets -->
            <xsl:when test="translate(substring($date1, 11), '+:', '')  > translate(substring($date2, 11), '+:', '')">
                <xsl:value-of select="$date2" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$date1" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Demo:  https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eixh2wr/2